# Unix script zip file creation not creating directories properly

Tags: unix

I just created a script file does a bunch of file coping and creates a zip file with directories.  The problem I am having is my syntax creates the zip file with my home directories included which I don’t want.

Meaning I get a zip file with this:

```
home/myname/parentdirectory/subdirectories/…
```

What I want is a zip file that starts at:

```
parentdirectory/subdirectories…
```

Syntax is:

```
zip –r myZipFile.zip ~/parentdirectory
```

What do I need to change this to?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd ~/
zip -r myZipFile.zip parentDirectory
```

You can view the `~/` as a shortcut/alias/abbreviation of '/home/myname/'. You're really specifying an absolute path, even though it's only "dynamically" absolute.